# apache redirect url, rewrite and elb not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I did searched over internet and couldn't find the answer about it. I have very limited or no knowledge about the rewrite rule. Can somebody help me or point me to the right direction.

Problem is like this:
 - I have a website: `example.com`

- I cannot access it with `example.com` but it work fine with `example.com/example/`
- I have tried couple of rewrite rule but couldn't make it work with `example.com`
- Here is my `.htaccess` which works with `example.com/example`

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /example/

  RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^doc.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^app.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

  RewriteRule ^assets/uploads/.*\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps?|fla|psd|log|sh|zip|exe|pl|jsp|asp|htm|sh|cgi|py)$ - [F]
  ```
- This web server is also behind the ELB and I have added this config inside the virtual host to redirect the `http` to `https`

```html
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

How I can make my webserver to access it with `example.com` and also redirect from `http` to `https`
Kindly help me with the rewrite rule etc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Below rule should work for in example directory please try,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am getting the blank page, still it didn't work for me.